# How do put Clipboard in its own thread to avoid STA threading issue

Tags: multithreading, reporting-services

I have a class DLL library that I built from a sample I found on a website. The class converts RTF to HTML. I call it from my SQL Server Reporting Services report. The problem is that the code is using the clipboard which needs its own thread.

The error in SSRS states:

Current thread must be set to single thread apartment (STA) mode before OLE calls can be made. Ensure that your Main function has STAThreadAttribute marked on it.

I tried implementing a thread by samples I found from the internet to no avail. Could some help show me how to take the clipboard piece of the function and put it in its own thread, and then when that is done, resume the function that builds the HTML string that sends it back to my SSRS report?

Here is the function:

```
Public Function sRTF_To_HTML(ByVal sRTF As String) As String
    'Declare a Word Application Object and a Word WdSaveOptions object
    Dim MyWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
    Dim oDoNotSaveChanges As Object = _
         Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges
    'Declare two strings to handle the data
    Dim sReturnString As String = ""
    Dim sConvertedString As String = ""
    Try
        'Instantiate the Word application,
        'set visible to false and create a document
        MyWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
        MyWord.Visible = False
        MyWord.Documents.Add()
        'Create a DataObject to hold the Rich Text
        'and copy it to the clipboard
        Dim doRTF As New System.Windows.Forms.DataObject
        doRTF.SetData("Rich Text Format", sRTF)

        'HERE IS WHERE THE CLIPBOARD STATEMENTS BEGIN


        Clipboard.SetDataObject(doRTF)
        'Paste the contents of the clipboard to the empty,
        'hidden Word Document
        MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.Paste()
        'â€¦then, select the entire contents of the document
        'and copy back to the clipboard
        MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.WholeStory()
        MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.Copy()
        'Now retrieve the HTML property of the DataObject
        'stored on the clipboard
        sConvertedString = _
             Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Html)

        'HERE IS WHERE THE CLIPBOARD STATEMENTS END


        'Remove some leading text that shows up in some instances
        '(like when you insert it into an email in Outlook
        sConvertedString = _
             sConvertedString.Substring(sConvertedString.IndexOf("<html"))
        'Also remove multiple Ã‚ characters that somehow end up in there
        sConvertedString = sConvertedString.Replace("Ã‚", "")
        'â€¦and you're done.
        sReturnString = sConvertedString
        If Not MyWord Is Nothing Then
            MyWord.Quit(oDoNotSaveChanges)
            MyWord = Nothing
        End If
    Catch ex As Exception
        If Not MyWord Is Nothing Then
            MyWord.Quit(oDoNotSaveChanges)
            MyWord = Nothing
        End If
        MsgBox("Error converting Rich Text to HTML")
    End Try
    Return sReturnString
End Function
```

My attempt to put the function in a thread did not work. Though I get no threading errors when I test the DLL in my solution using a form project to call it, I still get the threading error when calling it from a SQL Server Reporting Services report.

I tried the following thread and did not work.

```
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Threading
Imports System.Windows.Forms
Imports System.Collections.Generic
Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices

<AttributeUsage(AttributeTargets.Method)> _
Public NotInheritable Class clsGetHTMLfromRTF
   Inherits Attribute

   Private Sub New()
   End Sub

   <STAThread()> _
   Public Shared Function TranlslateRTFtoHTML(ByVal rtfText As String) As String
      Dim thread = New Thread(AddressOf ConvertRtfInSTAThread)
      Dim threadData = New ConvertRtfThreadData() With {.RtfText = rtfText}

      thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
      thread.isBackground = True
      thread.Start(threadData)
      thread.Join()
      Return threadData.HtmlText
   End Function

   Public Shared Sub ConvertRtfInSTAThread(ByVal rtf As Object)
      Dim threadData = TryCast(rtf, ConvertRtfThreadData)
      threadData.HtmlText = sRTF_To_HTML(threadData.RtfText)
   End Sub

   Public Class ConvertRtfThreadData
      Public Property RtfText() As String
         Get
            Return m_RtfText
         End Get
         Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_RtfText = value
         End Set
      End Property

      Private m_RtfText As String
      Public Property HtmlText() As String
         Get
            Return m_HtmlText
         End Get
         Set(ByVal value As String)
            m_HtmlText = value
         End Set
      End Property
      Private m_HtmlText As String
   End Class

   Public Shared Function sRTF_To_HTML(ByVal sRTF As String) As String
      'Declare a Word Application Object and a Word WdSaveOptions object
      Dim MyWord As Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.Application
      Dim oDoNotSaveChanges As Object = _
           Microsoft.Office.Interop.Word.WdSaveOptions.wdDoNotSaveChanges
      'Declare two strings to handle the data
      Dim sReturnString As String = ""
      Dim sConvertedString As String = ""
      Try
         'Instantiate the Word application,
         'set visible to false and create a document
         MyWord = CreateObject("Word.application")
         MyWord.Visible = False
         MyWord.Documents.Add()
         'Create a DataObject to hold the Rich Text
         'and copy it to the clipboard
         Dim doRTF As New System.Windows.Forms.DataObject
         doRTF.SetData("Rich Text Format", sRTF)
         Clipboard.SetDataObject(doRTF)
         'Paste the contents of the clipboard to the empty,
         'hidden Word Document
         MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.Paste()
         'â€¦then, select the entire contents of the document
         'and copy back to the clipboard
         MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.WholeStory()
         MyWord.Windows(1).Selection.Copy()
         'Now retrieve the HTML property of the DataObject
         'stored on the clipboard
         sConvertedString = _
              Clipboard.GetData(System.Windows.Forms.DataFormats.Html)
         'Remove some leading text that shows up in some instances
         '(like when you insert it into an email in Outlook
         sConvertedString = _
              sConvertedString.Substring(sConvertedString.IndexOf("<html"))
         'Also remove multiple Ã‚ characters that somehow end up in there
         sConvertedString = sConvertedString.Replace("Ã‚", "")
         'â€¦and you're done.
         sReturnString = sConvertedString
         If Not MyWord Is Nothing Then
            MyWord.Quit(oDoNotSaveChanges)
            MyWord = Nothing
         End If
      Catch ex As Exception
         Return ex.Message
         If Not MyWord Is Nothing Then
            MyWord.Quit(oDoNotSaveChanges)
            MyWord = Nothing
         End If
         'MsgBox("Error converting Rich Text to HTML" & vbCrLf & ex.Message)
      End Try
      Return sReturnString
   End Function
End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new Thread object and before you start the thread, call 
    SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA)
on it. In the thread procedure do your clipboard access.

Comment: Hi. Thank you for replying. I tried doing what you said to the entire function (see edited post), but still got the error. I just don't know how to thread just the clipboard portion.

Comment: In your new code, what line exactly gives you the exception?